# Duplicate payload type for same codec but different fmtp line is it valid scenario?

Tags: sip, codec, sdp

I am developing a voip application. In one of the scenario, I'm receiving following SDP from network:

```
`m=audio 10660 RTP/AVP 18 18 8 0 108
 a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes
 a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
 a=rtpmap:108 telephone-event/16000
 a=fmtp:108 0-15
 a=ptime:20`
```

There are 2 instances of payload type 18 for different fmtp line.
Is it valid scenario as per rfc?

Answer (score 1):

That scenario is not valid.

First its missing the rtpmap that identifies the codec, assuming its G729 due to the codec mention the offer should be something like:

```
 m=audio 10660 RTP/AVP 18 8 0 108
 a=rtpmap:18 G729/16000
 a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes
 a=rtpmap:108 telephone-event/16000
 a=fmtp:108 0-15
 a=ptime:20
```

Regarding the annexb part, if supported it should be offered with '=yes' then answerer has the option to accept with "=no" as per RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7261

Comment: Agreed with last line that it should send with yes, and answerer can reject with No.
In your SDP m line should contain only one 18 payload type.